# Best practice querying the DB using python

Tags: python, mysql-python, cx-oracle

Below is the code. In iterating the dictionary, the code is querying multiple times. Is it the best practice to execute the query or Pinging the DB multiple times ?

```
import cx_Oracle
connDev = 'username/password@hostname:port/service'
connDev = cx_Oracle.connect(connDev)

cursor = connDev.cursor()

d = {'2006': '20170019201',
    '2006172': '2017000002',
    '200617123': '200003'
}

for key,value in d.items():
    cursDev.execute('SELECT columnName from tableName where columnName={}'.format(key))
    if len(cursDev.fetchall())!=0:
        # cursDev.execute('UPDATE tableName SET columnName= {0} WHERE columnName= {1} '.format(value, key))

    else:
        continue

connDev.commit()
cursDev.close()
connDev.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run a single query and get everything:

```
cursDev.execute(
    'SELECT columnName FROM tableName WHERE columnName IN ({})'.format(
        ','.join(':p{}'.format(n) for n in range(len(d))),
    {'p{}'.format(n): k for n, k in enumerate(d)}
)
```

or run the updates directly - they do nothing if the row is not found:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    cursDev.execute(
        'UPDATE tableName SET columnName = {} WHERE columnName = :value',
        {'value': v}
    )
```

Note that both examples are using parameterized queries - the data is being passed separated from the query and it is the job of the database to do the parameter interpolation - thus freeing you from quote hell and preventing injection automatically, besides performing better.

The code uses `:value` named-style parameter placeholders because that is what `cx_Oracle` uses - see [documentation on `cx_Oracle.paramstyle`](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html).

Answer (score 0):

For a 'batch' update like this, the `executemany()` call is going to be most efficient way.

As @nosklo noted, the SELECT calls aren't necessary - they just take time.  And with `executemany()` you don't need to do repeated `execute()` calls, which is another saving.

From [`samples/ArrayDMLRowCounts.py`](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ArrayDMLRowCounts.py):

```
# delete the following parent IDs only
parentIdsToDelete = [20, 30, 50]

print("Deleting Parent IDs:", parentIdsToDelete)
print()

# enable array DML row counts for each iteration executed in executemany()
cursor.executemany("""
        delete from ChildTable
        where ParentId = :1""",
        [(i,) for i in parentIdsToDelete],
        arraydmlrowcounts = True)

# display the number of rows deleted for each parent ID
rowCounts = cursor.getarraydmlrowcounts()
for parentId, count in zip(parentIdsToDelete, rowCounts):
    print("Parent ID:", parentId, "deleted", count, "rows.")
```

See [Efficient and Scalable Batch Statement Execution in Python cx_Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/efficient-and-scalable-batch-statement-execution-in-python-cx_oracle) for more examples, including those with multiple binds like you will need.

[Never ever (except is specialized cases) build up a SQL statement by concatenating strings.  It is a security hole and can also give poor performance. Always use bind variables]